# Mouse doesn't work but lights up

Tags: mouse, 21.10

I use a wireless mouse with a laptop running Ubuntu 21.10. The mouse is part of a keyboard-mouse combo, which means that the USB dongle connects both. There are no other input devices connected, like a graphics tablet or keypad.

I went through my usual cleaning routine in the laptop. I ran these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo reboot
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt autoremove
```

The mouse was working well by then.

Then, I turned off the laptop and proceeded to clean the mouse and the keyboard. Here's what I did with the mouse:

1. Remove the batteries.
2. Wipe down the exterior of the mouse with a damp cloth. Damp with alcohol, by the way. Just to make it clear, I didn't wipe down the interior or the sensor-y thingy.
3. Wipe down the mouse again but with a dry part of the cloth.
4. Put back the batteries.

When I turned on the laptop, I noticed that even though the mouse lights up, it does nothing. In contrast, the keyboard works perfectly.

I've tried the following:

- Replacing the batteries with newer ones. Still the same.
- Putting those new batteries in another mouse to see if they're alright. Turns out that they are.
- Connecting the mouse to another machine. Same.
- Rebooting the laptop while the mouse was connected. Same again.
- Remove the mouse with the blueman program. If you don't know, this program lets you see devices connected by Bluetooth and screw around with them. However, neither the mouse or keyboard show up in the list.
- Connecting another mouse to the laptop. It works just well.
- Disconnecting the mouse from the current USB port and connecting to another USB port. Nope.
- Using the touchpad. It works flawlessly.
- Checking if the system recognizes the mouse. To do so, I ran `$ xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer` in a terminal. Since it returned information, it is recognized.
- Checking if the mouse speed is at 0 through the settings, but that's not the case.
- Checking the same as above but using the `xinput` and `xinput get-feedbacks X` commands. `X` in the last one is the ID of a device. The output of `xinput` is weird. None of the entries said "Cliptec" or "Essential Air". Just wayland-*something*. And if those were the keyboard and mouse, the properties are fine.

This is the output of `xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer` if anyone is interested:

```
2: "Virtual core pointer"   [XPointer]
4: "Virtual core XTEST pointer" [XExtensionPointer]
6: "xwayland-pointer:17"    [XExtensionPointer]
7: "xwayland-relative-pointer:17"   [XExtensionPointer]
```

Here's that of `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:17                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:17              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:17                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And that of `xinput get-feedbacks 6` which is also that of `xinput get-feedbacks 7`:

```
1 feedback class
PtrFeedbackClass id=0
    accelNum is 2
    accelDenom is 1
    threshold is 4
```

Information about the mouse:

- Brand: Cliptec
- Model: RZK339 Essential Air
- Tracking Engine: Optical
- Tracking DPI: 1000/1200/1600 DPI
- Operating Current: ≤10mA
- Input Power: 2*AAA Batteries
- Port: Wireless 2.4 GHz (USB)

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "Connecting the mouse to the family PC. Same."?  Does that mean that the mouse doesn't work on another PC?  If that is the case, sounds like the mouse is bad, whether it be the USB dongle or the mouse itself, hard to say exactly which one.

Comment: @Terrance
Yes, it's another machine. I'll edit the post so it's clearer.

Also, the mouse is the more likely to be damaged. The dongle not only connects the mouse, but also a keyboard. And the keyboard works fine.

Comment: Note the mount lighting up means that it's getting power but does not mean that data is being tranmeted.

Comment: You put back the same weak batteries?

Comment: @David, nope. I put back new batteries. Those batteries work well with another mouse.

Comment: @Inee I'm not sure if I got you. Are you asking me to add to the post what you said?

Comment: You may want to edit the question and add that detail.

Comment: @David Done. Just added that.